# Jenkinsfile Trigger a job from quay.io trigger plugin

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, webhooks, dockerhub

I am attempting to move from a Freestyle Project to a multibranch pipeline build.  I would like my Jenkinsfile to trigger when a new container has been pushed to my Quay.io repository.  In the Freestyle Project I'm able to accomplish this with the Quay.io Trigger Plugin. 
Moving to the Multibranch build pipeline I've found this [post](https://www.toger.us/blog/2017/06/17/jenkins-and-github-hooks/), that describes how to trigger on a dockerhub trigger.  I've also used the Jenkins Pipeline Syntax "wizard" to generate the code to add to my Jenkinsfile:

```
properties([[$class: 'ScannerJobProperty', doNotScan: false], [$class: 'RebuildSettings', autoRebuild: false, rebuildDisabled: false], [$class: 'ThrottleJobProperty', categories: [], limitOneJobWithMatchingParams: false, maxConcurrentPerNode: 0, maxConcurrentTotal: 0, paramsToUseForLimit: '', throttleEnabled: false, throttleOption: 'project'], pipelineTriggers([[$class: 'QuayIoTrigger', repositories: ['hostedsparkbots/janitorbot-timer', 'hostedsparkbots/janitorbot', 'hostedsparkbots/sparky']]])])
```

In the above case when I do a scan of my github repository I get a **wall** of backtraces from the jenkins console:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@712ddbf9
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4447.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.Setter$1.set(Setter.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.injectSetters(DescribableModel.java:338)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:261)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {repositories=[hostedsparkbots/janitorbot-timer, hostedsparkbots/janitorbot, hostedsparkbots/sparky]} for QuayIoTrigger(repositories?: String[])
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:264)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:380)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerceList(DescribableModel.java:461)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:365)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:318)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:259)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {triggers=[{$class=QuayIoTrigger, repositories=
```

Does anybody actually have this working in a Jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

If you cast the collection of repositories as a `java.util.Set` in the Jenkinsfile, this works as expected. Using your list above, you'd want to do this:

```
#!groovy
@import java.util.Set  // this may not be required?
properties([
    pipelineTriggers([[
        $class: 'QuayIoTrigger',
        repositories: (['hostedsparkbots/janitorbot-timer',
                        'hostedsparkbots/janitorbot',
                        'hostedsparkbots/sparky'] as Set)
    ]])
])
```

The background:

I had been struggling to figure this out myself, but ultimately dug through the [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/quayio-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/quayio/trigger/QuayIoTrigger.java) in the Quay.io Trigger Plugin. The current plugin isn't designed with Jenkins Pipeline in mind, so [it uses a Set](https://github.com/jenkinsci/quayio-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/quayio/trigger/QuayIoTrigger.java#L46) in the constructor for the repository collection.

This is where the cast exception is occurring, as Groovy is treating the list of strings as an array, an not able automatically cast this into a Set.

By explicitly creating the list of repositories as a Set, the plugin is configurable in the `Jenkinsfile`.

Hope this helps!